# Layering maps with different axes

Tags: python, geopandas, shapefile

I am new to python, trying to create a map using geopandas with two layers. One layer is a shapefile of the city of Portland's neighborhoods, the other is a data set with latitudes and longitudes in Portland that I want to pin.

Each plots fine on its own (i.e. I've gotten that far), but layering doesn't work because the coordinates used for the city of Portland map aren't in latitude longitude form.  There are instructions on Portland's open data website for how to use QGIS to convert a shapefile to a geoJSON, and in doing so setting the CRS to EPSG:4269, but I don't know how to do this in Python with the shapefile.

Images show each plotting fine until I try to plot them together, note the axes...

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,15))
street_map.plot (ax = ax, alpha = .4, color ='grey')
```

[image: Portland shapefile]

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,15))
#street_map.plot (ax = ax, alpha = .4, color ='grey')
geo_df[geo_df['price']>250].plot(ax=ax, markersize = 20, color = 'blue', marker = "o")
```

[image: pins without borders]

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,15))
street_map.plot (ax = ax, alpha = .4, color ='grey')
geo_df[geo_df['price']>250].plot(ax=ax, markersize = 20, color = 'blue', marker = "o")
```

[image: failed layering because axes don't match]

Comment: Welcome to python! It would help us a lot if you posted all the code necessary to get to where you're stuck - ideally including a link to the shapefile. As some of the answers have pointed out you can definitely align these but you need to know the source CRS for the shapefile. And how are you reading in the shapefile? Fiona or geopandas or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I have looked for data you reference, but only find **geojson** that are in consistent CRS (EPSG:4326).  If you have a **GeoDataFrame** in another CRS, as per other comment, use `to_crs("EPSG:4326")` to make geometries consistent.

```
import requests
import geopandas as gpd
import plotly.express as px

# boundaries
gdf_b = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(
    requests.get(
        "https://www.portlandmaps.com/arcgis/rest/services/Public/COP_OpenData_Boundary/MapServer/3/query?outFields=*&where=1%3D1&f=geojson"
    ).json()
)
# water fountains
gdf_wf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(
    requests.get(
        "https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/070f61b58ac646b0aaf2a223b2dd16fa_84.geojson"
    ).json()
)


px.scatter_mapbox(
    gdf_wf, lon=gdf_wf.geometry.x, lat=gdf_wf.geometry.y, hover_data=["COMMENTARY"]
).update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "style": "carto-positron",
        "layers": [{"source": gdf_b.__geo_interface__, "type": "fill", "opacity": 0.3}],
    }
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

did you try the geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs() method yet to change the crs inside python?

https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html

Comment: I didn't try that yet because the crs I need to change is for the shapefile ... is that a geodataframe, or do I need to convert it to one first?

Comment: you can have a look at the type of your "streetmap" object to make sure, but I am pretty confident it is because you can use the plot() method which works on geodataframes

Comment: I was able to solve this problem by using the to_crs() method on street map. It was a simple fix!